# Unexpected output while printing vector elements

Tags: c++, vector

I am just getting started with vectors and what I wanted to do was to create a vector of size 3 with float data type and print out the elements. Here is what I did

```
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>

using namespace std;

int main() 
{ 
    int n;
    cin>>n;
    float ip;
    vector<float> v;
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        v.push_back(ip);
        cin>>ip;
    }

    for (auto i = v.begin(); i != v.end(); ++i) 
        cout << *i << " "; 
}
```

EXECUTION 
1st input is the size of vector
the following lines contain the data

3
11.2
23.4
33.1

Expected output

11.2 23.4 33.1

What I actually get

5.88233e-39 11.2 23.4
I Dont understand what this first value is and how can I overcome it any kind of help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Think about the order of operations in your first loop.

Comment: What is the initial value of `ip`, that you `push_back` to your `std::vector`?

Comment: The program has undefined behavior since the vector is storing a copy of an uninitialized floating point variable.

Comment: What the people here want to tell you is that you need to write ````cin>>ip;        v.push_back(ip);```` But meanwhile you figuered that out by yourself

Comment: In the place of e-34 I want the first no. I gave as input and so on. I even tried with ip=0 then I am getting 0 11.2 23.4 but what I actually want is 11.2 23.4 33.1 as the output

Comment: I think you need to re-read what you write in first for cycle. prompt: 1. get input, 2. add to the array

Comment: *I want the first no. I gave as input* -- Then follow the logic of your program.  You get the first value (other than `n`) **after** you called `push_back`.  The input doesn't magically look backwards in the program and places the value in the vector for you.  The computer does exactly what you tell it to do.  Don't know how much simpler to explain it.

Comment: Thanx Man understood it. It was quite a silly mistake tbh.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

when you just write "float inp;" the variable inp has a random value because it isn't initialized. then you add this random value to your vector and after that you read your first input . just switch the lines inside the first for loop and it should work.

Answer (score 0):

A number with e-34 means that this number is so small in magnitude that it is essentially equivalent to '0'. This often happens when you allocate a data structure of double but have not assigned a value to it. In your program, you are not assigning to `ip` before inserting it into your data structure. I suggest you figure out the logic to your program in pseudocode before coding it.

Comment: In the place of e-34 I want the first no. I gave as input and so on. I even tried with ip=0 then I am getting 0 11.2 23.4 but what I actually want is 11.2 23.4 33.1 as the output